# How to create algorithm to make simple calculation on values in string column in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string, numpy, character

I have DataFrame like below, data type of col1 is str:

```
col1
---------
46081402525
77020220486
1233GGdP
NaN
....
```

And I need to select only rows that **DO NOT** meet the conditions described below:

For example algorithm for the first value in "col1" (46081402525) is as below, so the last character in this value should be 4. The last character in this value is not 4, so this value DO NOT meet the conditions below

1. Multiply each digit (except the last one) from "col" 1 by the corresponding weight: 1-3-7-9-1-3-7-9-1-3
   for example:

- 4*1 = 4
- 6*3 = 18
- 0*7 = 0
- 8*9 = 72
- 1*1 = 1
- 4*3 = 12
- 0*7 = 0
- 2*9 = 18
- 5*1 = 5
- 2*3 = 6

2. Add together the obtained results. Note, if you get a two-digit number when multiplying, add only the last digit (for example, instead of 18 add 8).
   4+8+0+2+1+2+0+8+5+6 = 36
3. Subtract the result you get from 10. Note: if you get a two-digit number during addition, subtract only the last digit (for example, instead of 36 subtract 6).
   10 - 6 = **4**

So as a result i need:

```
col1
---------
77020220486
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas? Of course be aware that in "col1" sometimes could be value with character (not only numbers) or NaN.

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts? For example, defining a function and using `df.apply()` seems like a good place to start

Comment: I do not any idea yet :/

Answer (score 1):

The solution should look as follows.

Given a Pandas frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ["46081402525", "77020220486", "1233GGdP", "NaN"]})
```

you can use the method

```
def deriveValue(x:str):
    x = str(x)
    parameterSeq = '13791379130' # added 0 in the end to match lengths
    try:
        y = int(x)
    except:
        return ''
    
    if len(x)!=11:
        return ''
    else:
        output = sum([int(digit)*int(para)%10 for digit,para in zip(x,parameterSeq)])
        
    return 10 - output % 10
```

Applying it to the dataframe `df` via

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(deriveValue)
```

yields

[image]

Please note, however, that the sequence of weights is of length 10 while the input sequence you provided is of length 11. Therefore, I appended the weights with a `0` at the end. You might want to modify this.

Since the numbers at each steps have at most 2 digits, the modulo operation `%10` will provably work as you specified (neglecting the 1st digit if there are two).

Comment: 7shoe I have and error when I use your code: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable this error is in line: output = sum([int(digit)*int(para)%10 for digit,para in zip(x,parameterSeq)])  what should i do ?

Comment: Rerunning the code still works for me. However, I added a minor adjustment `y = int(x)` instead of `int(x)` in the 5th line of the method. Did you assign something like `int = ...` in your code before? If the error persists please share the Python version you run the code on. It is outputted when you run `!python -V` in a jupyter cell or `python -V` in the terminal.

Comment: Still does not wokr I have: Python 3.8.8 version of Python :/ and you ?

Comment: Thanks. Python 3.9 and 3.10. It works fine on both. In addition, it runs on here, too. See this online [Python editor](https://trinket.io/python3/ee16919eb7)

Comment: How can I upgrade version from 3.8.8 to 3.9 or 3.10 ?

Comment: I don't believe that is necessary - at all. `int` is the built-in type in Python since its inception. Your bug is different and likely stems from a copy-paste error or previous code. Restart the kernel of the jupyter notebook. Check each line of code. Indentation errors, maybe? If not, start from scratch. Define a simple example, e.g. `[int(i) for i in range(5)]` and run it. Build incrementally more complicated examples until the error pops up, e.g. `[int(i) for i in ["1", "2"]]`. Whatever its source, it's not in my code above.